# wxPython: Getting a EVT_KEY_DOWN event for CMD+[other key] on OSX

Tags: macos, wxpython

I'm trying to catch an event when the user presses COMMAND + [any other key] on OSX. Since these are actually two key presses I expect two events: One when COMMAND is pressed and one when the other key is pressed (without releasing the COMMAND key). This works fine for every modifier except COMMAND where I only get the first event. Why is that and how can I fix it?

Version: wxPython3.0-osx-cocoa-py2.7

Example code:

```
import wx

def OnKeyDown(e):
    print "Modifiers: {} Key Code: {}".format(e.GetModifiers(), e.GetKeyCode())

app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None)

textctrl = wx.TextCtrl(frame, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.WANTS_CHARS)
textctrl.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, OnKeyDown)

frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

For ALT + d the output is:

```
Modifiers: 1 Key Code: 307
Modifiers: 1 Key Code: 68
```

For SHIFT + d the output is:

```
Modifiers: 4 Key Code: 306
Modifiers: 4 Key Code: 68
```

Only for COMMAND + d the output is:

```
Modifiers: 2 Key Code: 308
```

Thanks for your help

**Additional Information:** I'm using OSX 10.8 on a *virtual machine*. As RobinDunn points out that it works on his laptop. So chances are that this is just a problem in my environment. wnnmaw provided a good workaround which works for me even on the virtual environment.

Comment: What version of OSX are you using? Are you using any non-standard keyboard mapping, IME, or system addon that handles global hot-keys?  I am on 10.8 and I am getting the key event for the Cmd+d here.  BTW, you should also try with the KeyEvent sample in the demo to ensure that it is not a matter of the key event being stolen by the native widget.

Comment: This is definitely something you want to solve with accelerator tables

Comment: @RobinDunn: I'm using 10.8 as well but I'm running it in a VM on Windows. This could be the reason even though I'm still sceptical because CMD+d works in other non-wxpython applications without problems. I guess I need to get my hands on a real apple machine for further testing.

Comment: @wnnmaw: I'm trying to implement a settings dialog where the user can choose his/her own shortcuts (similar to the ShortcutEditor, which btw. has the same problem on my machine). Since I don't know which shortcut the user will choose, I can't use an accelerator table.

Comment: I get the same result with the KeyEvent demo

Comment: @JonasPfannschmidt, sure you could, you can create and alter acceleration tables on the fly, you just need to be clever about it

Comment: @wnnmaw: Could you point me to some documentation/examples? I always thought AcceleratorTables need to be configured upfront.

Comment: I'll get a working example together at some point today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so it took me some time, but here's a working code block that does what you want.

**Some Things to Note:**

- I did this on Windows (so there are some changes you can make such as adding support for `wx.ACCEL_RAW_CTRL` which corresponds to the actual control key on Mac whereas `wx.ACCCEL_CTRL` corresponds to the command key
- This code definitely can (and needs to be) cleaned up
- You'll have to add better error checking before you give this to a user

Whithout further adieu, here it is

```
import wx
from wx.lib.scrolledpanel import ScrolledPanel

class TestWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'Accelerator Table Test', size=(600, 400))

        self.panel = ScrolledPanel(parent=self, id=-1) 
        self.panel.SetupScrolling()

        #Create IDs to be used in initial acclerator table
        self.functionList = [self.func1, self.func2, self.func3, self.func4, self.func5, self.OnAdd, self.OnDel]
        self.functionListstr = ["self.func1", "self.func2", "self.func3", "self.func4", "self.func5", "self.OnAdd", "self.OnDel"]
        self.IDDict = {i: wx.NewId() for i in range(len(self.functionList))}
        self.IDDictrev = {val:key for key, val in self.IDDict.iteritems()}

        self.aTableList = [(wx.ACCEL_ALT, ord('S'), self.IDDict[0]),(wx.ACCEL_CTRL, ord('Q'), self.IDDict[1])]

        #Set up initial accelerator table
        aTable = wx.AcceleratorTable(self.aTableList)
        self.SetAcceleratorTable(aTable)

        #Bind inital accelerator table IDs to functions
        for i in range(len(self.functionList)):
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.functionList[i], id=self.IDDict[i]) 


        #Set up control widgets on GUI    
        self.flexgrid = wx.FlexGridSizer(cols=3, hgap=10, vgap=5)

        cmdkeylbl = wx.StaticText(self.panel, -1, "Command Key") 
        self.cmdkey = wx.ComboBox(self.panel, style=wx.CB_READONLY)
        cmdkeylist = ["Alt", "Control/Command", "Shift", "OSX Control", "None"]
        self.cmdkeyconstants = {"Alt":wx.ACCEL_ALT, "Control/Command":wx.ACCEL_CTRL, "Shift":wx.ACCEL_SHIFT, "None":wx.ACCEL_NORMAL}
        self.cmdkeyconstantsrev = {val:key for key, val in self.cmdkeyconstants.iteritems()}
        self.cmdkey.SetItems(cmdkeylist)

        hotkeylbl = wx.StaticText(self.panel, -1, "HotKey (single letter only)") 
        self.hotkey = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, size=(50,-1))

        funclbl = wx.StaticText(self.panel, -1, "Function") 
        self.func = wx.ComboBox(self.panel, style=wx.CB_READONLY)
        self.func.SetItems(self.functionListstr)

        self.hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        addBtn = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, "Add")
        delBtn = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, "Delete")

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnAdd, addBtn)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnDel, delBtn)

        self.vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.curATable = wx.StaticText(self.panel, -1, self._DisplayATable())

        self.flexgrid.Add(cmdkeylbl)
        self.flexgrid.Add(hotkeylbl)
        self.flexgrid.Add(funclbl)
        self.flexgrid.Add(self.cmdkey)
        self.flexgrid.Add(self.hotkey)
        self.flexgrid.Add(self.func)

        self.hbox.Add((20, 20), 0)
        self.hbox.Add(addBtn)
        self.hbox.Add((0, 0), 0)
        self.hbox.Add(delBtn)
        self.hbox.Add((20, 20), 0)

        self.vbox.Add(self.flexgrid, flag=wx.TOP|wx.BOTTOM|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.EXPAND, border = 5)
        self.vbox.Add(self.hbox, flag=wx.TOP|wx.BOTTOM|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.EXPAND, border = 5)
        self.vbox.Add(self.curATable, flag=wx.TOP|wx.BOTTOM|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.EXPAND, border = 5)

        self.panel.SetSizer(self.vbox)
        self.panel.Layout()

    #Class Functions
    def _DisplayATable(self):
        aTablelbl = ""
        for cmdKey, hotKey, Func in self.aTableList:
            aTablelbl += "{} + {} calls {}\n".format(self.cmdkeyconstantsrev[cmdKey], chr(hotKey), self.functionListstr[self.IDDictrev[Func]])

        return aTablelbl

    def OnAdd(self, event):
        self.aTableList.append((self.cmdkeyconstants[self.cmdkey.GetValue()], ord(self.hotkey.GetValue()[:1].title()), self.IDDict[self.func.GetSelection()]))
        print "Added {} + {} as a shortcut for {}!".format(self.cmdkey.GetValue(), self.hotkey.GetValue()[:1].title(), self.functionListstr[self.func.GetSelection()])

        aTable = wx.AcceleratorTable(self.aTableList)
        self.SetAcceleratorTable(aTable)
        self.curATable.SetLabel(self._DisplayATable())
        self.panel.Layout()

    def OnDel(self, event):
        if (self.cmdkeyconstants[self.cmdkey.GetValue()], ord(self.hotkey.GetValue()[:1].title()), self.IDDict[self.func.GetSelection()]) in self.aTableList:
            self.aTableList.remove((self.cmdkeyconstants[self.cmdkey.GetValue()], ord(self.hotkey.GetValue()[:1].title()), self.IDDict[self.func.GetSelection()]))

            aTable = wx.AcceleratorTable(self.aTableList)
            self.SetAcceleratorTable(aTable)
            self.curATable.SetLabel(self._DisplayATable())
            self.panel.Layout()

        else:
            dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, "ERROR: That combination is not in the accelerator table!", "Error", style=wx.OK)
            dlg.ShowModal()
            dlg.Destroy()

    def func1(self, event):
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, "Func1", "Func1", style=wx.OK)
        dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()

    def func2(self, event):
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, "Func2", "Func2", style=wx.OK)
        dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()

    def func3(self, event):
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, "Func3", "Func3", style=wx.OK)
        dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()

    def func4(self, event):
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, "Func4", "Func4", style=wx.OK)
        dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()

    def func5(self, event):
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, "Func5", "Func5", style=wx.OK)
        dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()

app = wx.App(False)
frame = TestWindow()
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Hopefully this is what you're looking for, let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Thank you very much. It's not exactly what I wanted but it'll do and CMD+x works perfectly. I need to do some more work to support special keys (e.g. F1-F12) but you brought me on the right track.
Ideally I would have liked just one input field that captures whatever key-combination the user enters (see ShortcutEditor).

Comment: This should be pretty easy to modify yo get what you want. I'm not sure how to use the F keys with this, I'll look into it